# using a dynamic list of gulp tasks in run-sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, run-sequence

I am creating some gulp tasks with dynamic task names. These tasks need to be run in order, not parallel. I am putting the task names in an array, but I am getting an error from run-sequence. I assume this error is a problem with how I am listing the tasks from the array in my [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence) code.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var taskNames = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3']
```

Then for run sequence I'm trying to do this:

```
gulp.task('run-dynamic-tasks', function(){
  runSequence(
    taskNames.join(", \n"),
    function(){
      browserSync.reload();
    }
  );
});
```

This does not work and gives this error:

> Error: Task task1,
>
> task2,
>
> task3 is not configured as a task on gulp.  If this is a submodule (error continues)

Please note, if there is only *one* task in the array, such as:

```
var taskNames = ['task1']
```

then this code works.

I believe this is probably a javascript mistake, as opposed to run-sequence or node.

thank you for any and all help,
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed a basic javascript problem. I should have been using [function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Final gulp.task is this:

```
gulp.task('run-dynamic-tasks', function(){
  runSequence.apply(null, taskNamesArray);
});
```